# inside class calling form1 sub

Tags: vb.net, class

Hey all i am trying to call a public sub within a class that resides within my form1 code:

```
 Public Class Form1
    Public Shared objItem As ListViewItem

    Class Server
        Private Shared Sub StringMessageReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As StringMessageEventArgs)
          MsgBox("Received message: " & Convert.ToString(e.Message))
          'Form1.ListView1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(e.Message))
          Call Form1.writeToLV(Convert.ToString(e.Message))
        End Sub

    End Class

  Public Sub writeToLV(ByRef theStuff As String)
    MsgBox(theStuff)
    objItem = ListView1.Items.Add(theStuff)
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ListView1.View = View.Details
    ListView1.Columns.Add("Response", CInt(500))
  End Sub
 End Class
```

It sends the value over just fine but when it gets to putting it into the listview it never does?

Any pointers?

David

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the form that has been opened on the screen is not the default instance referenced by Form1 in the Server class.

I think that you need to restructure your code somewhat: if you are only going to have one instance of Form1, explicitly create the form and keep a reference to it in a global variable (i.e. g_Form1) rather than relying on the VB-provided default instance (assuming you are ever only going to have 1 instance of the form.

If you can have more than 1 instance of Form1, I would convert your internal Server static class to an Interface and when a new form is created, have it register itself with whatever mechanism is calling Server.StringMessageReceived.